# Get current opened document

Tags: c#, api, lotus-notes

I'm trying to figure out how to get the currently opened document on Lotus Notes through C#, but I cannot. Even though I researched half a day on Google, I couldn't find anything useful.

With my code I get the view I want, the database I want, etc, but I just would like to get the opened document. I tried something like IsUIDocOpen, but none of the full collection contains it as true.

Does someone know if there is any different between an opened document and a non-opened document trough Domino API? My workaround is to get the subject of the email and the size of the email and compare each one and when it matches get the Entry ID and then get the information I need - but that takes too long, especially when the inbox is big.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
NotesSession session = new NotesSession();

session.Initialize(sPassword);
notedb = session.GetDatabase(server, filename, false);
if (notedb.IsOpen)
{
  mailView = notedb.GetView("$Inbox");

  mailDoc = mailView.GetLastDocument();
  //mailDoc = mailView.GetDocumentByKey();
  try
  {
    while (mailDoc != null)
    {
      NotesItem item = mailDoc.GetFirstItem("From");

      if (item != null)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("From = " + item.Text);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Solution: should be something like:  `mailDoc = mailView.GetCurrentDocument();` // But obviously this method does not exist :D

=====================================================================================
Solution code:

```
Type NotesUIWorkspaceType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace", true);
object workspace = Activator.CreateInstance(NotesUIWorkspaceType);
object uiDoc = NotesUIWorkspaceType.InvokeMember("CurrentDocument", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, workspace, null);
Type NotesUIDocument = uiDoc.GetType();
object Subject = NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("FieldGetText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uiDoc, new Object[] { "Subject" });
string subject = "test";

NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("FieldSetText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uiDoc, new Object[] { "Subject", subject });
object Body = NotesUIDocument.InvokeMember("FieldGetText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, uiDoc, new Object[] { "Body" });
```

Comment: Are you using the Domino API or the Lotus Notes Interop COM classes ? If you're using Domino, it will never work : it gives you access to the database on your Domino server, not the Lotus Notes program.

Comment: Where can I find the Lotus Notes Interop COM classes?thanks

Comment: Have a look here : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-msnet/index.html . It's for VB.Net, but if I remember correctly, in C# you have access to wrapper classes in the namespace that allow you to create the classes.

Answer (score 3):

What you actually need is the Notes OLE classes.

The C# Interop classes are based on the Notes COM classes.  The COM classes only have access to the "back end".  I.e., the root object is Lotus.NotesSession, and all the classes work against data stored in .NSF files.  They have no access to anything in the Notes UI.

The Notes OLE classes have access to both the "back end", with the root object Notes.NotesSession, and the "front end" with the root object Notes.NotesUIWorkspace.  As you can tell by the name of that class, it's the front end classes that give you access to elements of the Notes client UI.

*Note the subtle difference: the prefix for the OLE classes is "Notes.", instead of the prefix "Lotus." for the COM classes.*

In old-style VB late binding, the OLE classes are instantiated this way:

```
CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
```

I'm not sure how that translates into C#.
Anyhow, once you have the NotesUIWorkspace object, the currently opened document is available with the `NotesUIWorkspace.CurrentDocument` method.

Comment: Thank you Richard, I have some progress thank of you:

    Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace", true);
    object ThisInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

Answer (score 2):

IF you are using the Interop Classes you need to use `NotesUIView.CurrentView.Documents` to get what you want... see [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_NOTESSESSION_CLASS.html).

Comment: I am using interop.Domino but I cannot see NotesUIView.. any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to get the NotesUIWorkspace first, then use the [CurrentDocument](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CURRENTDOCUMENT_PROPERTY.html) property

```
NotesUIWorkspace workspace = new NotesUIWorkspace();
NotesUIDocument uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument();
```